# Manfrotto broken leg lever

Tags: tripod, manfrotto, repair-parts

Bought a Manfrotto Befree Advanced tripod yesterday. The lever lock version. After opening/closing like 3 times one of the leg lock levers is broken. I found on manfrotto parts website a spare for 8 EUR + VAT + shipping from Italy to Hungary.

My questions are

1. Does warranty include this? There are 2 years. (I guess I will have an answer next Monday from the retailer)
2. Any aftermarket options for parts? I'm not willing to spend such money considering the price of the tripod itself.
3. Any DIY options that would still allow me to fold the tripod completely?

Talking of plastic. Is there any way to have the same part made of metal (e.g. alu)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send it back. EU law says you're completely protected.

It didn't need to even break if you bought it online, you can send it back for any reason inside 14 days. You pay postage, though, if you just "don't want it"

As it's broken, they pay postage. You can have either money back or free replacement.

Look up your own country's equivalent of "online selling regulations" or "distance selling regulations".

I am not a lawyer, but I've thrown this set of rules in many suppliers' faces. They don't have a leg to stand on… in your case, quite literally ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if either the screw tensioner was too tight or the plastic was defective. Mail them and ask them for a replacement part under warranty. You should also be able to 3D print a piece, but would probably have to oversize the cam portion to better distribute the forces.